# Problems with using NDSolveValue to solve two-dimensional Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, numerical-value

When I use NDSolveValue to solve the following two-dimensional Fokker-Planck equation, it works well:

```
\[Sigma] = 0.5;
x0 = 0.;
y0 = 0.;
tmax = 1.;

Mpl = 1.;
lambda = 0.1;
M = 0.1;
xi = 0.1;
reg = Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}];

Omega[s_] := Sqrt[2./3.] s/Mpl;
U[s_, h_] := 
  Exp[-2. Omega[s]]*(3./4. Mpl^2*
      M^2*(Exp[Omega[s]] - 1 - (xi*h^2)/Mpl^2) - 
     lambda/4.*h^4);
Vs[s_, h_] := 
  Exp[-2. Omega[s]]*(Sqrt[1./6.] lambda/Mpl h^4 + 
     Sqrt[3./2.] Mpl*
      M^2*(Exp[Omega[s]] - 1. - (xi*h^2)/Mpl^2)*(1. + (xi*h^2)/
        Mpl^2));
Vh[s_, h_] := 
  Exp[-Omega[s]]*(-3. M^2*xi*h*(Exp[Omega[s]] - 1. - (xi*h^2)/Mpl^2) -
      lambda*h^3);
H[s_, h_] := Sqrt[Mpl/3.] U[s, h];

Eqn = D[P[t, s, h], t] - 
    D[Vs[s, h]/(3. H[s, h]) P[t, s, h] + 
      H[s, h]^(3/2)/(8. Pi^2) D[H[s, h]^(3/2) P[t, s, h], s], s] - 
    D[Vh[s, h]/(3. H[s, h]) P[t, s, h] + 
      H[s, h]^(3/2)/(8. Pi^2) D[H[s, h]^(3/2) P[t, s, h], h], h] == 0;

B = Erf[(1 - x0)/(Sqrt[2] \[Sigma])] + 
   Erf[(1 + x0)/(Sqrt[2] \[Sigma])];
f[x_, y_] = 
  1/B (2/(\[Pi] \[Sigma]^2))^(1/2)
    Exp[(-(x - x0)^2 - (y - y0)^2)/(2 \[Sigma]^2)];

uifWave = 
  NDSolveValue[{Eqn, P[0, s, h] == f[s, h], 
    DirichletCondition[P[t, s, h] == 0., True]}, 
   P, {t, 0, tmax}, {s, h} \[Element] reg];

(*framesWEQ=Table[Plot3D[uifWave[t,s,h],{s,h}\[Element]uifWave[\
"ElementMesh"],PlotRange->All,Boxed->False,Axes->True,AxesLabel->\
Automatic],{t,0,tmax,tmax/100}];
Manipulate[framesWEQ[[i]],{{i,16,"time"},1,Length[framesWEQ],1},\
SaveDefinitions->True]*)
```

But when I change `reg = Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}];` to `reg = Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}];`, it comes out with the error says:

> NDSolveValue: The function value {$Failed} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1281} at {t, P[t, s, h], *SuperscriptBox["P", TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None][t, s, h]}) = 0.000443123,{<<1>>},{-3.1083*10^-44,-4.15261*10^-40,-2.04091*10^-36,<<5>>,-2.18102*10^-23,-9.77463*10^-23,<<1271>>}}.

What's the problem?

Comment: Mathematica 12.2 evaluates both cases without error!

Comment: Mma 12.0 evaluated the first case without error, but the message for the second case reads: "At t == 0.0004436100591033273`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected"

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Yes, I also meet this message when I change tmax or reg.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I use Mathematica 13.1

Comment: @user21 I set the boundary to be P(boundary) = 0, and my initial condition is a two-dimensional gaussian distribution, whose center is at origin. And reg = Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}] should satisfy P(boundary) = 0 better than the previous case.

Comment: I think the problem may be the accuracy is not enough, because when I run `Plot3D[{uifWave[tmax/100, s, h]}, {s, h} \[Element] uifWave["ElementMesh"], PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> Automatic]`, the probability quickly becomes non-smooth at the very beginning. I try several `Method`, but most of them do not work, I can only use `Method->Automatic`. Maybe it is because it is a two-dimensional PDE, I want to know what method can I use to solve this kind of PDE.

Comment: Also, the tensor product method can not solve this: `uifWave = 
 NDSolveValue[{Eqn, P[0, s, h] == f[s, h], 
   P[t, -5, h] == P[t, 5, h] == P[t, s, -5] == P[t, s, 5] == 0.}, 
  P, {t, 0, tmax}, {s, -5, 5}, {h, -5, 5}]`

Comment: There is only machine precision for FEM. See this: FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions

Comment: @user21 what is tensor product method, it seems similar to mine.

Comment: @JieJiang The tensor product method uses finite differences for spatial discredization and the method of lines for converting time integration. See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html)